# Python: Force heapq.merge to interpert strings as integers during comparison

Tags: python, sorting, casting, merge

I'm attempting to merge a group of pre-sorted files where every line in each file is an integer:

```
for line in heapq.merge(*files):
```

The sort completes successfully but the comparison is done on the file contents as strings, not integers. How can I force the integer comparison?

Comment: Cannot store files in memory, need to read large files on fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for line in heapq.merge(*(map(int, file) for file in files)):
```

That doesn't interpret the strings as integers during comparison, but actually on-the-fly *changes* them to integers. The outcome is therefore integers, not strings. Can of course then be converted back to strings if desirable:

```
for line in map(str, heapq.merge(*(map(int, file) for file in files))):
```

For others / future reference: This is for Python 3, where `map` returns an iterator. In Python 2, `map` would need to be replaced by `itertools.imap` in order to not read everything into memory at startup.

Comment: @RedLeader Just to be sure: You're using Python 3, right?

Comment: @RedLeader Ok good :-) In Python 2 it would have to be itertools.imap instead of map.

Comment: @RedLeader Thanks for pointing out heapq.merge, btw. I didn't know it's a normal merge, I would've thought it merges heaps only into a heap (not necessarily fully sorted).

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the files and converting each line into an integer. This assumes that all data fit into memory.

```
def read_as_int_list(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as fobj:
        return [int(line) for line in fobj]
```

This should be more memory efficient:

```
def read_as_ints(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as fobj:
        for line in fobj:
            yield int(line)
```

Usage:

```
files = (read_as_ints(name) for name in list_of_file_names)
for line in heapq.merge(*files):
    print(line)
```

Comment: Should have added that condition. Cannot store the values in memory and that's why I'm trying to use this implementation to read the top of each input stream on the fly.

Comment: @RedLeader Added a version that should work with large files. Let me know if it works for you.